# iOS - Background transfer Tasks don't match

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I'm trying to upload my iOS photo's from the camera roll to an external server via a background fetch call. To accomodate this, i loop through ALAssetsLibrary in the background fetch to look for new photos. When new photos are found or all photo's in case of a new device, i initiate a background transfer for that photo. My plan was to start a NSURLSession and add a few tasks per fetch.

This works. The files get uploaded. But the callbacks are inconsistent. After simulating a lot of background fetches, one in a hundred times the didCompleteWithError callback isn't fired. But the biggest problem is that the Tasks don't match a lot of the times. when i check the task Identifier after creating a single task with:

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullFileName isDirectory:NO];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [_session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:theURL];
NSLog(@"Task id at start: %d", [uploadTask taskIdentifier]);
```

And in the callback:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Didcomplete - task_id: %d", [task taskIdentifier]);
...
```

My output is:

```
2013-12-31 14:02:36.628 Project[18685:1303] Didcomplete - task_id: 30
2013-12-31 14:02:36.768 Project[18685:70b] Task id at start: 31
```

I guess i already read somewhere that the output does not have to be linear because of the background tasks. But because the identifiers differ, i can't match the output to the task and proccess the background task correctly after it's finished.

Anyone has an idea what could cause this behavior? Or what i could try?

Comment: Put breakpoints on the log statements - when are they hit? The id should be logged before the completion method is called...

Comment: @Wain I used the breakpoints. If i set a breakpoint after the first log, the one after creating the task, it will display without the didcomplete log. But if i put the breakpoint after the didcomplete log, the first log will not show... What i also observed, after using the simulator a few times. Deleting the app from the simulator and compiling again, sometimes several (old) Tasks call a didcomplete on a background fetch: 

14:01:25.329 ... Didcomplete - task_id: 129
14:01:25.345 Didcomplete - task_id: 124
14:01:25.349 Didcomplete - task_id: 128
14:01:25.351 Task id at start: 132

Comment: I would recommend testing on a read device. Also, bear in mind that iOS 7 spreads background activity around so you can't assume anything about how long things will take to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a simulator issue. When testing on a real device, the task identifiers match up in the didcomplete callback and proper processing of the request is possible.